# is it possible to merge duplicate event locations?

Tags: civievent, duplicate-contacts, location

Multiple events have taken place at the same location, but there are multiple listings of the same location. Is it possible to merge these locations without losing any of the data from the events?

On CiviCRM 5.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Location details for events are stored in a sql table called civicrm_loc_block which brings together an address an email and a phone number for each event.

At a push you could identify the affected events and update them so they all share the same loc_block id. But that would need to be done by querying/updating the SQL tables.

Basically, there isn't a function to address this in the user interface.